# Batch echo %var(number of %ifno%)%

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

```
@echo off
set varno=1
for /r %%A in (*.txt) do call :loopdo "%%A"
goto end
:loopdo
set var=%1
set var=%var:*libraries\=%
set var%varno%=%varno%. %var:.txt"=%
set /a varno=%varno%+1
goto :eof
:end
set ifno=1
if %ifno% LSS %varno% (
echo %var%%ifno%
set /a ifno=%ifno%+1
)
pause
```

How could I make this echo %var1% %var2% etc?
At the moment it just echoes textfile1.txt"1 textfile2.txt"2 and I can see why but I don't know how to make it do the above.
I have tried %varifno% and %%var%ifno%% but they don't work - again I can see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to evaluate variables within a variable name, `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.  Also, use variable expansion to strip the `.txt` off the end of the filename within your `:loopdo` subroutine.  You're pretty close otherwise.

```
@echo off
set varno=1
for /r %%A in (*.txt) do call :loopdo "%%~pnA"
goto end
:loopdo
set "var=%~1"
set "var=%var:*libraries\=%"
set /a varno+=1
goto :eof
:end
set ifno=1
if %ifno% LSS %varno% (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo !var%ifno%!
    endlocal
    set /a ifno+=1
)
pause
```

This is untested, as your use of `var%varno%` and `%var%%ifno%` is a little confusing.  I don't see that you're ever actually setting a variable called `%var%%ifno%`.  Hopefully the changes I made will lead you in the right direction, if it doesn't provide the complete solution.

Comment: thanks a lot, in the end i included the if in the for loop but the delayed expansion helped, what i was doing is it lists all the text files in a folder and then it will ask you to select 1, 2 or 3 etc